# filter entity fields on symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

How can I choose(filter) on my controller which fields I want (or don't want) to pass to my frontend?

my Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="dashboard")
 */
public function index()
{

    $aniversariantes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Usuario::class)->aniversariantes();

    return $this->render('dashboard/index.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'DashboardController',
        'aniversariantes' => $aniversariantes
    ]);
}
```

My repository:

```
/**
 * @return []
 */
public function aniversariantes(): array
{
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->andWhere('u.ativo = 1')
    ->andwhere('extract(month from u.dtNascimento) = :hoje')
    ->setParameter('hoje', date('m'))
    ->getQuery();

    return $qb->execute();
}
```

Dump from entity:

[image]

What can I do if I don't want to pass the "password" field for example?

Comment: Did you try the method `select()` of createQueryBuilder? Like `$this->createQueryBuilder('u')->select('u.id, u.sobrenome')`

Comment: I did, but i want to use custom methods from the entity, when i use the select() I can't call them.

Comment: You are are passing entities to your template, if you do not want something passed to frontend (browser) simply do not render it in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to prevent certain fields from being dumped, it is useful to know

> Internally, Twig uses the PHP var_dump function.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/dump.html

This means you can can define the PHP magic method `__debugInfo` in your entity

> This method is called by var_dump() when dumping an object to get the properties that should be shown. If the method isn't defined on an object, then all public, protected and private properties will be shown.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo

So in your entity do something like this:

```
class Usuario {
    ...

    public function __debugInfo() {
        return [
            // add index for every field you want to be dumped 
            // assign/manipulate values the way you want it dumped
            'id' => $this->id,
            'nome' => $this->nome,
            'dtCadastro' => $this->dtCadastro->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
    }

    ...
}
```